# Windows command line cut the extension of this syntax

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I found this script and I modified it for my use but I'm not good in Windows batch.

Can anyone help me with cutting the extension from `%%x`?

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
pushd %CD%
cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        unzip -o -d %%X
    )
popd
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get only the name without the extension, use `~n`in the variable : `%~nX` at command line or escaped in the batch file `%%~nX`

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
pushd %CD%
cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        unzip -o -d %%~nX
    )
popd
)
```

You can get the reference for variable expansion in the MS Technet [For page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e275726c-035f-4a74-8062-013c37f5ded1).